# How can I get scrolling event to register?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, scroll

I'm trying to program a webpage animation where a user can have the choice of clicking & dragging or simply scrolling using the mouse wheel to view a vertical stack of images. Click & drag works fine, however the scrolling input doesn't work as desired. When I attempt to scroll though the pictures, input doesn't seem to register. When I click & drag first, and then scroll, the scroll feature works.

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>CoolEffect</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "image-track" data-mouse-down-at = "0" data-prev-percentage = "0">
        <img class="image" src="assets/photo-1542051841857-5f90071e7989.jpeg" draggable="false">
        <img class="image" src="assets/photo-1533050487297-09b450131914.jpeg" draggable="false">
        <img class="image" src="assets/photo-1564284369929-026ba231f89b.jpeg" draggable="false">
        <img class="image" src="assets/photo-1528360983277-13d401cdc186.jpeg" draggable="false">
        <img class="image" src="assets/photo-1492571350019-22de08371fd3.jpeg" draggable="false">
        <img class="image" src="assets/photo-1532884928231-ef40895eb654.jpeg" draggable="false">
        <img class="image" src="assets/photo-1540959733332-eab4deabeeaf.jpeg" draggable="false">
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#image-track > .image {
    width: 150vmin;
    height: 50vmin;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: 100% 0%;
}

#image-track {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

JavaScript

```
const track = document.getElementById("image-track");

window.onmousedown = e => {
    track.dataset.mouseDownAt = e.clientY;
}

window.onmouseup = () => {
    track.dataset.mouseDownAt = "0";
    track.dataset.prevPercentage = track.dataset.percentage;
}

window.onmousemove = e => {
    if(track.dataset.mouseDownAt === "0") return;

    const mouseDelta = parseFloat(track.dataset.mouseDownAt) - e.clientY,
    maxDelta = window.innerHeight;

    let percentage = (mouseDelta / maxDelta) * -100,
    nextPercentage = parseFloat(track.dataset.prevPercentage) + percentage;

    nextPercentage = Math.max(-100, Math.min(0, nextPercentage));

    track.dataset.percentage = nextPercentage;

    track.animate(
        {transform :`translate(-50%, ${nextPercentage}%)`}, 
        {duration: 1200, fill: "forwards"});

    for(const image of track.getElementsByClassName("image")){
        image.animate(
            {objectPosition : `50% ${nextPercentage + 100}%`}, 
            {duration: 1200, fill: "forwards"});
    }
} 

window.addEventListener("wheel", e => {

    e.preventDefault();
    
    const deltaY = e.deltaY;
    const maxDelta = window.innerHeight;
    
    let percentage = (deltaY / maxDelta) * -100,
        nextPercentage = parseFloat(track.dataset.percentage) + percentage;
    
    nextPercentage = Math.max(-100, Math.min(0, nextPercentage));
    
    track.dataset.percentage = nextPercentage;
    
    track.animate(
        { transform: `translate(-50%, ${nextPercentage}%)` },
        { duration: 1200, fill: "forwards" }
    );
    
    for (const image of track.getElementsByClassName("image")) {
        image.animate(
            { objectPosition: `50% ${nextPercentage + 100}%` },
            { duration: 1200, fill: "forwards" }
        );
    }
    scrollStartY = e.pageY;
});
```

What I expected to happen was regardless of previous input, the user can scroll or click & drag to view the images. Without clicking and dragging first, the user is unable to do so. I first thought the issue lied in the default scrolling behaviour of the page, so I added to e.preventDefault() to negate this. This however wasn't the issue. Any suggestions as to what could be causing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only modifying the track.dataset.percentage value when scrolling, but you're not updating track.dataset.prevPercentage to reflect the current state.

```
let scrollStartY = 0;

window.addEventListener("wheel", e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const deltaY = e.deltaY;
    const maxDelta = window.innerHeight;

    let percentage = (deltaY / maxDelta) * -100,
        nextPercentage = parseFloat(track.dataset.percentage) + percentage;

    nextPercentage = Math.max(-100, Math.min(0, nextPercentage));

    track.dataset.prevPercentage = track.dataset.percentage; // Update prevPercentage
    track.dataset.percentage = nextPercentage;

    track.animate(
        { transform: `translate(-50%, ${nextPercentage}%)` },
        { duration: 1200, fill: "forwards" }
    );

    for (const image of track.getElementsByClassName("image")) {
        image.animate(
            { objectPosition: `50% ${nextPercentage + 100}%` },
            { duration: 1200, fill: "forwards" }
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I also needed to retrieve the previous percentage of movement when calculating nextPercentage (parseFloat(track.dataset.prevPercentage)). Now it works